# Aggregate function applied on the result returned by relationships() function throwing error

Tags: postgresql, cypher, apache-age

I have three nodes named: **A**,**B** and **C** and there is a relationship between **A->B** and **B->C** named '**EDGE',** which has a property named **cost**.

So I am trying to find out the **total cost** from A to C, using the **relationships()** function to first find the edges in between and then sum up the **cost** on edges/relationship using **sum()** function. So my query becomes:

```
SELECT * from cypher('demo_graph', $$

      MATCH p = (a:Vertex {name: 'A'})-[:EDGE*]->(c:Vertex {name: 'C'})
      WITH relationships(p) AS edges
      RETURN sum(edge.cost) AS totalCost

$$) as (V agtype);
```

But this query return the following error:

[image]

Do someone know what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that the aggregate function `sum()` is used to add values of row(s) within a single column but here the `relationships(p)` returns a list of edges and hence you cannot add the values of this list. One way to do it is to use the `UNWIND` clause to first break down the list of edges to multiple rows with each row consisting of a single edge and then use the `sum()` aggregate function on these rows as used here.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('demo_graph', $$
MATCH p = (u:Vertex {name : "A"})-[:EDGE*]->(v:Vertex{name : "C"})
UNWIND(relationships(p)) AS x RETURN sum(x) 
$$) AS (result agtype);
```

PS: previously there was a check for edge type in UNWIND and the following error was displayed

> ERROR:  UNWIND clause does not support agtype edge

but with the latest commit [here](https://github.com/apache/age/pull/736), UNWIND can work with edges. ***You need to pull the recent changes using `git pull` to use this feature as it recently got merged.***