# How to find all possible routes along with the time travelled?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I have created a few nodes called routes and have given several relationships that are travel times as shown below.

```
SELECT *
FROM cypher('Map', $$
    CREATE (a:Route {name: 'A'}), 
        (b:Route {name: 'B'}),
        (c:Route {name: 'C'}),
        (d:Route {name: 'D'}),
        (e:Route {name: 'E'}),
        (f:Route {name: 'F'}),
        (a)-[:Connects {time: 4}]->(b),
        (a)-[:Connects {time: 2}]->(c),
        (b)-[:Connects {time: 6}]->(c),
        (b)-[:Connects {time: 9}]->(d),
        (c)-[:Connects {time: 1}]->(d),
        (c)-[:Connects {time: 8}]->(e),
        (c)-[:Connects {time: 3}]->(f),
        (d)-[:Connects {time: 3}]->(a),
        (e)-[:Connects {time: 10}]->(b),
        (f)-[:Connects {time: 2}]->(e)
$$) AS (x agtype);
```

I am trying to find all possible connections for specified routes along with the total time travelled. For example, if I want the information from Route 'A' to Route 'F', how would I do so? I am not concerned about the shortest path but just want all the possible routes.

Comment: I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715176/18610676). Hope it helps!

Comment: There is a similar [github issue](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/730) related to this. Check it out as well.

Comment: I've tried the solutions suggested in the posts, but they did not work. The `sum()` function works as expected; however, the `UNWIND` clause causes an issue `ERROR: UNWIND clause does not support agtype edge`.

Comment: I have also mentioned that UNWIND did not support edge type but this issue was resolved in a recent merge. So, you need to pull the changes and rebuild AGE.

Comment: Oops I must have missed it. I've pulled and rebuilt AGE and the `UNWIND` error has been resolved. When I run the [query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715176/19164563) however, the resulting table shows 1 empty row for the result. The `MATCH` query I've used was `MATCH p = (u:Route {name: 'A'})-[:EDGE*]->(v:Route {name: 'C'})`, which should have at least one result as I explicitly made a connection between them but even this is not showing up.

Comment: what does `UNWIND(relationships(p)) AS x RETURN x` output? Is it an empty row as well?

Comment: `UNWIND(relationships(p)) AS x RETURN x` results in an empty table with 0 rows.

Comment: Noted. Let me look into it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('stack75718178',$$
    MATCH p=(a:Route {name:'A'})-[:Connects *]->(b:Route {name:'F'})
    WITH p, relationships(p) as edges
    UNWIND edges as edge
    RETURN p, sum(edge.time)
$$) as (path agtype, totalcost agtype);
```

Result:

```
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                  path                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                           | totalcost 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842626, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "prope
rties": {"time": 2}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842630, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131973, "start_id
": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 8}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131973, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "E"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842633, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 
844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131973, "properties": {"time": 10}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842628, "lab
el": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131972, "start_id": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 9}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"i
d": 1125899906842632, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131969, "start_id": 844424930131972, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {
"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842625, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"time": 4}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label"
: "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842627, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 6}}::edge, {"id"
: 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842631, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131974, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties":
 {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]::path | 45
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842626, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "prope
rties": {"time": 2}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842629, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131972, "start_id
": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 1}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842632, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 
844424930131969, "start_id": 844424930131972, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842625, "labe
l": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"time": 4}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id
": 1125899906842627, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 6}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"
name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842631, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131974, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131974, "label":
 "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]::path                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                           | 19
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842625, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131969, "prope
rties": {"time": 4}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842627, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id
": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 6}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842631, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 
844424930131974, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]::path                         
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                           | 13
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842626, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "prope
rties": {"time": 2}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842631, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131974, "start_id
": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]::path                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                           | 5
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842625, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131969, "prope
rties": {"time": 4}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842628, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131972, "start_id
": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 9}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842632, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 
844424930131969, "start_id": 844424930131972, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842626, "labe
l": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"time": 2}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id
": 1125899906842631, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131974, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"
name": "F"}}::vertex]::path                                                                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                           | 21
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842626, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "prope
rties": {"time": 2}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842630, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131973, "start_id
": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 8}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131973, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "E"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842633, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 
844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131973, "properties": {"time": 10}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842627, "lab
el": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 6}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"i
d": 1125899906842631, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131974, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {
"name": "F"}}::vertex]::path                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                           | 29
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842625, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131969, "prope
rties": {"time": 4}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842627, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id
": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 6}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842629, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 
844424930131972, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 1}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842632, "labe
l": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131969, "start_id": 844424930131972, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id
": 1125899906842626, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"time": 2}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"
name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842631, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131974, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131974, "label":
 "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]::path                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                           | 19
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842625, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131969, "prope
rties": {"time": 4}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842627, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id
": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 6}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842630, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 
844424930131973, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 8}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131973, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "E"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842633, "labe
l": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131973, "properties": {"time": 10}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"i
d": 1125899906842628, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131972, "start_id": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 9}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {
"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842632, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131969, "start_id": 844424930131972, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131969, "label"
: "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842626, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"time": 2}}::edge, {"id"
: 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842631, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131974, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties":
 {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]::path | 45
 [{"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842625, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131969, "prope
rties": {"time": 4}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842628, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131972, "start_id
": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 9}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131972, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "D"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842632, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 
844424930131969, "start_id": 844424930131972, "properties": {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131969, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "A"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842626, "labe
l": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131969, "properties": {"time": 2}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id
": 1125899906842630, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131973, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties": {"time": 8}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131973, "label": "Route", "properties": {"
name": "E"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842633, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131970, "start_id": 844424930131973, "properties": {"time": 10}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131970, "label"
: "Route", "properties": {"name": "B"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842627, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131971, "start_id": 844424930131970, "properties": {"time": 6}}::edge, {"id"
: 844424930131971, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "C"}}::vertex, {"id": 1125899906842631, "label": "Connects", "end_id": 844424930131974, "start_id": 844424930131971, "properties":
 {"time": 3}}::edge, {"id": 844424930131974, "label": "Route", "properties": {"name": "F"}}::vertex]::path | 45
(9 rows)
```

Comment: I'm getting the `ERROR: UNWIND clause does not support agtype edge` even after pulling the latest version of age and reinstalling it. How did you get it to work and also what versions of PostgreSQL and AGE are you using for this?

Comment: Please follow the method described here https://github.com/apache/age/issues/761#issuecomment-1481530424 to rebuild age. I am using postgres 11.17.

Comment: I'm using postgres 12. Maybe that's the reason for the issues?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason... PG12 branch for AGE hasnt been updated with the recent commits done to master....

Answer (score -1):

The way I think that you can solve it, is coding a DFS (Depth First Search). Marking all the visited nodes, and doing an `if` if the destination node has not been visited, and calling the dfs function recursively with this node as the new node parameter.

You can write your own codes to run on **Apache AGE**, you just have to save it at:

```
age/src/backend/utils/
```

I found this code in C language, maybe it can help you!

[Depth First Search(DFS)](https://scanftree.com/programs/c/c-program-to-implement-depth-first-search-dfs/#:%7E:text=Depth%20First%20Search%20is%20an,Breadth%20First%20Search(BFS).)